# Bypassing or automating user interaction during program installation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm creating a batch script to install a few applications.

My script :

```bat
echo Installation of Adobe Reader
echo.
start /wait C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\readerdc_en_ra_install.exe /sp- /verysilent

echo Installation of HSDM
echo. 
start /wait C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\HP_SDM_Setup.exe /sp- /verysilent

echo Installation of Ninite
echo.
start /wait C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\NiniteBase.exe
```

Some of the installations once invoked require user interaction; *they ask me to click on "next" "next" "install" etc.*

How do I bypass the user interaction completely, or at least automate it?

Comment: How about VBS `sendKeys`?

Comment: Those switches look suspect? Usually an exe command for silent is just /S?

Comment: /S not work :'(